# Remove password from PDF file with PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Once I upload a protected PDF with password through a PHP page, I need to remove the password (stored in hardcoded way) with some PHP function and then save the current unprotected PDF file in the server's filesystem.
Do you know any method / library to do it?

Thank you
Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use gs to remove password. Try:

```
exec("gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=unencrypted.pdf -c .setpdfwrite -f encrypted.pdf");
```

Comment: One question: with your workaround where I need to pass the PDF's password to the script?

Comment: no need to pass password

Comment: If I run the command above from inside a PHP script I get this error: 

**** This file requires a password for access.
GPL Ghostscript 9.07: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Comment: Any news???? :)

Comment: By my command you can remove password about print, copy of file... if you don't have passoword for opening you can do nothing.